# How can I make , a footer section, visible only in my wordpress frontpage?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created 5 widgets sections for my template footer. Now I would like to know, how is possible to make a footer section only visible in my front page theme and the other widgets in all other pages? So footer 5 widget appears in front page and the footer4 in other pages!

Here is what I wrote, but it doesn't work!

```
<?php if (is_home()): if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar(is_active_sidebar('footer5'))){?>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
 <?php get_dynamic_sidebar('footer5'); ?>
 </div><?php }?>
 <?php elseif(is_active_sidebar('footer4')) : ?>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 socialiconsfooter">
 <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer4'); ?>
 </div><?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to print footer5 widget you need to change `get_dynamic_sidebar('footer5')` to `dynamic_sidebar('footer5')`

```
<?php
 if(is_home()):
    if(function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && is_active_sidebar('footer5')){
        echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">';
        dynamic_sidebar('footer5');
        echo '</div>';
    }
    elseif(function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && is_active_sidebar('footer4')){
        echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">';
        dynamic_sidebar('footer4');
        echo '</div>';
    }
 endif;
 ?>
```

The above code should work. It will show widget only on front page.

EDIT:
To show widgets on every page the below code should work.

```
<?php
    if(function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && is_active_sidebar('footer5')){
        echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">';
        dynamic_sidebar('footer5');
        echo '</div>';
    }
    elseif(function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && is_active_sidebar('footer4')){
        echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">';
        dynamic_sidebar('footer4');
        echo '</div>';
     }
?>
```

Comment: thank a lot. It was useful. Now it works but only in frontpgae, in the other pages it doesn't appear any widget. So I'm trying to fix that.

Comment: Your question was to make it visible only on the front page.

Comment: Ok I will edit my answer to add the widget on other pages too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is now solved by this code. Thanks a lot @danish.

```
if(is_front_page()&& function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && is_active_sidebar('footer5')){
                echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">';
                dynamic_sidebar('footer5');
                echo '</div>';
            }else
            if(!is_front_page() && function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && is_active_sidebar('footer4')){
                echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 socialiconsfooter">';
                dynamic_sidebar('footer4');
                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Wordpress for showing particular code block on specific pages there are lots of conditional functions available.

For checking **[if the current page is Home page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home)** and **[Check If current page is a custom page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/)**.

After checking the conditional you can **[load the specific sidebar](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar)** or **[a specific widget instance](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget)** on any specific page or section.

For more functions just follow the **[wordpress codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/)**.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kapil.

Comment: Your welcome @Krenar , You can ask anything related to wordpress.